# Is the `chrome.runtime` API no longer available from regular pages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Several months ago, I played with some code that used the `chrome.runtime` API from within a regular page's JS runtime (meaning, not an extension's background script).

Now, using that same code, `chrome.runtime` is `undefined`. Did something change?

I've got a background script that listens for external messages, and I'd like to send a message to the extension using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` from a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome.runtime.sendMessage` should be available to your page if you have an installed extension which lists your site as `externally_connectable`. [See here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: Oh, thanks so much. That's got to be it. I was looking around a bit too frantically and whizzed by this. But of course--since the aforementioned code experimenting, I had changed the domain and forgot about this manifest flag.